# Delete Sitecore JSS Items after deploy

Tags: jss

We created a banner component using "**jss banner scaffold**" and deployed in sitecore using "**jss deploy app -c -d**".

Now we want to delete this component, is their any command for delete all items(templates, rendering, items) related to this component.

We can manually delete by Sitecore, but is there any way using command.

Thanks
Rishi

Comment: Possible option is to create an SPE script to do it

Answer (score 2):

Currently deleting items is not supported via the command line.

The only way to do this is during initial development with the `--wipe` or `-w` argument but you will need to set the `SitecoreJSS.WipeAllowed` to `true` in the Sitecore settings configuration.

As a warning this will wipe all data on your site as well so only use during initial development.

Reference: https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/fundamentals/dev-workflows/code-first#import-full-wipe-mode